# Dbpedia sparql gives empty result to my query, what is wrong?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm doing sparql query in this [site](https://dbpedia.org/sparql).
It gives me an empty result, what is wrong with my query?

```
prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
select * where {
?s rdf:type foaf:Person.

} LIMIT 100
```

This query is ok, but when I add the second pattern, I got empty result.

`?s foaf:name 'Abraham_Robinson'.`

```
prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
select * where {
?s rdf:type foaf:Person.
?s foaf:name 'Abraham_Robinson'.
} LIMIT 100
```

How to correct my query so the result includes this record:

http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abraham_Robinson

Comment: 1. when using literals, it has to be an exact match, i.e. the `_` char has to be removed. 2. literals can have language tags, which is also here the case: `prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
select * where {
?s rdf:type foaf:Person.
?s foaf:name 'Abraham Robinson'@en.
} LIMIT 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess [Kingsley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213503/kingsley-uyi-idehen) misread this as a freetext search, rather than a simple string comparison.

[The query Kingsley posted](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=prefix%20foaf%3A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0Aselect%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20rdf%3Atype%20foaf%3APerson.%0D%0A%3Fs%20foaf%3Aname%20%22%27Abraham_Robinson%27%22.%0D%0A%7D%20LIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) and linked earlier [delivers no solution](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20foaf%3A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0Aselect%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20rdf%3Atype%20foaf%3APerson.%0D%0A%3Fs%20foaf%3Aname%20%22%27Abraham_Robinson%27%22.%0D%0A%7D%20LIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), for the same reasons as the original query failed, as identified in the comment by AKSW, i.e. --

- `foaf:name` values don't generally replaces spaces with underscores as in the original value; i.e., `'Abraham_Robinson'` should have been `'Abraham Robinson'`
- `foaf:name` strings are typically langtagged, and it is in this case, so that actually needs to be `'Abraham Robinson'@en`

Incorporating AKSW's fixes [with this line `?s foaf:name 'Abraham Robinson'@en.`](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=prefix%20foaf%3A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0Aselect%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20rdf%3Atype%20foaf%3APerson.%0D%0A%3Fs%20foaf%3Aname%20%27Abraham%20Robinson%27%40en.%0D%0A%7D%20LIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), the [query works](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20foaf%3A%20%20%20%20<http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F>%0D%0Aselect%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20rdf%3Atype%20foaf%3APerson.%0D%0A%3Fs%20foaf%3Aname%20%27Abraham%20Robinson%27%40en.%0D%0A%7D%20LIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).

All that said -- you may prefer an alternative query, which will deliver results whether or not the `foaf:name` value is langtagged and whether or not the spaces are replaced by underscores.  [This one](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20foaf%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20*%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%20%20%20%20rdf%3Atype%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3APerson%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%20%20%20%20%3Fname%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fname%20%20bif%3Acontains%20%20%22%27Abraham%20Robinson%27%22%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) is Virtuoso-specific, and [produces results faster](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20%20foaf%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20*%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%20%20%20%20rdf%3Atype%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3APerson%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%20%20%20%20%3Fname%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fname%20%20bif%3Acontains%20%20%22%27Abraham%20Robinson%27%22%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) because the `bif:contains` function uses its free-text indexes, would be --

```
PREFIX  foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT * 
WHERE
  {
    ?s     rdf:type      foaf:Person ;
           foaf:name     ?name .
    ?name  bif:contains  "'Abraham Robinson'" . 
  } 
LIMIT 100
```

[Generic SPARQL using a `REGEX FILTER`](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX++foaf%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+*+%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fs+++++rdf%3Atype++++++foaf%3APerson+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++foaf%3Aname+++++%3Fname+.%0D%0A++++FILTER+%28+REGEX+%28+%3Fname%2C+%27Abraham+Robinson%27+%29+%29+.+%0D%0A++%7D+%0D%0ALIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+) works against both Virtuoso and other RDF stores, but [produces results more slowly](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX++foaf%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+*+%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fs+++++rdf%3Atype++++++foaf%3APerson+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++foaf%3Aname+++++%3Fname+.%0D%0A++++FILTER+%28+REGEX+%28+%3Fname%2C+%27Abraham+Robinson%27+%29+%29+.+%0D%0A++%7D+%0D%0ALIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+) because `REGEX` does not leverage the free-text indexes, as in --

```
PREFIX  foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT * 
WHERE
  {
    ?s     rdf:type      foaf:Person ;
           foaf:name     ?name .
    FILTER ( REGEX ( ?name, 'Abraham Robinson' ) ) . 
  } 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Yep! I misread the original problem assuming text index related issues.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work. Right now it isn't working due to a need to refresh the text index associated with this instance (currently in progress):

```
PREFIX foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT * where {
?s rdf:type foaf:Person.
?s foaf:name "'Abraham Robinson'".
} 
LIMIT 100
```

Note how the phrase is placed within single-quotes that are within double-quotes.

If the literal content is language-tagged, as is the case in DBpedia the exact-match query would take the form (already clarified in @TallTed's response):

```
PREFIX foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT * where {
?s rdf:type foaf:Person.
?s foaf:name 'Abraham Robinson'@en.
} 
LIMIT 100
```

This [SPARQL Results Page Link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix+foaf%3A++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0Aselect+*+where+%7B%0D%0A%3Fs+rdf%3Atype+foaf%3APerson.%0D%0A%3Fs+foaf%3Aname+%27Abraham+Robinson%27%40en.%0D%0A%7D+LIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+) should produce a solution when the index update completes.